# How to search in text file by line number in java?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on Hadoop MapReduce. I have created the MapReduce program which do Inverted index for our large Apache logs. The output of the MapReduce looks like this :

```
{"Error" {log1 {200,300,500}, log2{400,900,800..}}

{"201" {log5 {250,350,550}, log2{850,950,80..}}

{"400" {log3 {280,380,580}, log2{480,980,880..}}
```

Here I am going to store the word with it's inverted Index value as where it's appear in log file with it's name.

Now I want to write sample script/program which through I can search the log by it's line number. I am going to use above MarPreduce output. How can I do through java?

Example: if user search error in apache log, I am going to use log1,log2 and display the  records which are in 200,300,400 line

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader;
int lineCount = 0;
int lineYouWant = 100;
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("sample.txt")));
while (reader.ready()) {
   String line = reader.readLine();
   lineCount++;
   if (lineCount == lineYouWant) doStuff();
```

Use the above as a starting point. You have to read in the entire file (up to the point where you find the lines you want) since that's the only way to "count" the number of lines.

Comment: Is it directly jump into the line number or I need to iterate whole file till line number ? In practical scenario, the file is very huge like 1GB+ and more than 1m records

Comment: You have to iterate the whole file until the line number. How else do you know what "line number" you're even on? New lines are represented by a "newline" character such as \n that is OS dependent. Files aren't stored in memory according to where their "newlines" are. That would result in lots of wasted space.

Comment: @AmitNagar It would seem that Hadoop could easily help you handle even the largest log files. If your log files are too large, split them into parts and have different machines index the different parts, tracking how many newlines are in each part. Then you can figure out where your 200th line is.